# Disable Button Loop (NStimer or MouseMove) XCode Objective-C MacOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstimer

I am just experimenting with disabling a button with various methods on XCode MacOS (not iOS) Cocoa Objective-C.

In this scenario I have a help button (m_btHelp) that is disabled when g_bEnableHelpButton = NO; but it is only being checked when the mouse moves.

```
-(void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    
    if(g_bEnableHelpButton) {
        [m_btHelp setEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        [m_btHelp setEnabled:NO];
    }
```

I would rather have this continuously checked instead of only checked when the mouse moves. I have tried NSTimer with something like this, but it does not seem to work (m_btHelp does not get disabled when g_bEnableHelpButton = NO; like it does in the mouseMoved event:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(Timerloop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)Timerloop
{
     if(g_bEnableHelpButton) {
         [m_btHelp setEnabled:YES];
     } else {
         [m_btHelp setEnabled:NO];
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging this? What's the value of `m_btHelp` inside `TimerLoop`? Is it nil? How do you assign `m_btHelp` in your application delegate? (Presumably where the second code sample is coming from...)

Comment: Changing the button's enabled state from the timer function should work. Maybe try toggling the enabled value in the timer loop instead of setting to the global, just to verify - iyou should see the enabled state switch off and on every second.

Comment: Do it through `NSView` where you can set `NSTrackingArea`.  You should stay away from `Timer`, which is evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g_bEnableHelpButton` is a global variable, right? Don't use global variables. It's way better to create a class which holds your state (can be view model, ...). I'm going to skip a state class in all examples below and will use `BOOL helpButtonEnabled` property on the same view controller (this is not mandatory, it just makes all these examples a bit shorter). You can move this property elsewhere, it can be a state class, it can be basically any object.

Another thing is this `NSTimer`, `NSTrackingArea`, ... With all these things one is wasting CPU cycles, battery life, ... Cocoa & Objective-C offers various ways how to monitor a property value and react to it. You can override property setter, you can use KVO or bindings. All three methods are covered in examples below.

There are other ways for sure (like ReactiveCocoa), but I'd like to demonstrate three ways how to achieve it without dependencies.

### Initial state

Imagine you have this view:

[image]

With the following implementation:

```c
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

// Help button from the Main.storyboard
// Imagine it's your m_btHelp
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSButton *helpButton;

// Property driving helpButton enabled/disabled state
// Imagine it's your g_bEnableHelpButton
@property (nonatomic, getter=isHelpButtonEnabled) BOOL helpButtonEnabled;

@end

@implementation ViewController

// Just another button action coming from the Main.storyboard which toggles
// our helpButtonEnabled property value
- (IBAction)toggleHelpButtonEnabled:(id)sender {
    self.helpButtonEnabled = !self.helpButtonEnabled;
}

@end
```

There's help button and there's toggle button which just toggles `helpButtonEnabled` value (`YES` -> `NO`, `NO` -> `YES`).

How to monitor it without timer, tracking area, ... to update the help button state?

### Override setter

[Encapsulating Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html).

```c
@implementation ViewController

// This is setter for the helpButtonEnabled property.
- (void)setHelpButtonEnabled:(BOOL)helpButtonEnabled {
    // If the new value equals, do nothing
    if (helpButtonEnabled == _helpButtonEnabled) {
        return;
    }

    // Update instance variable
    _helpButtonEnabled = helpButtonEnabled;
    // Update button state
    _helpButton.enabled = helpButtonEnabled;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // When the view loads update button state to the initial value
    _helpButton.enabled = _helpButtonEnabled;
}

// Just another button action coming from the Main.storyboard which toggles
// our helpButtonEnabled property value
- (IBAction)toggleHelpButtonEnabled:(id)sender {
    self.helpButtonEnabled = !self.helpButtonEnabled;
}

@end
```

### KVO

[Introduction to Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

```c
static void * const ViewControllerHelpButtonEnabledContext = (void*)&ViewControllerHelpButtonEnabledContext;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)dealloc {
    // Remove previously registered observer when the view controller goes away
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"helpButtonEnabled" context:ViewControllerHelpButtonEnabledContext];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Register observer for the helpButtonEnabled key path
    //  - it fires immeditately with the current value (NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial)
    //  - it fires later every single time new value is assigned (NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew)
    //  - context is used to quickly distinguish why the observeValueForKeyPath:... was called
    [self addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"helpButtonEnabled"
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context:ViewControllerHelpButtonEnabledContext];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == ViewControllerHelpButtonEnabledContext) {
        // It's our observer, let's update button state
        _helpButton.enabled = _helpButtonEnabled;
    } else {
        // It's not our observer, just forward it to super implementation
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}

// Just another button action coming from the Main.storyboard which toggles
// our helpButtonEnabled property value
- (IBAction)toggleHelpButtonEnabled:(id)sender {
    self.helpButtonEnabled = !self.helpButtonEnabled;
}

@end
```

### Binding

[Introduction to Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html).

```c
@implementation ViewController

- (void)dealloc {
    // Remove binding when the view controller goes away
    [self.helpButton unbind:NSEnabledBinding];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // self.helpButton.enabled is binded to self.helpButtonEnabled
    [self.helpButton bind:NSEnabledBinding
                 toObject:self
              withKeyPath:@"helpButtonEnabled"
                  options:nil];
}

// Just another button action coming from the Main.storyboard which toggles
// our helpButtonEnabled property value
- (IBAction)toggleHelpButtonEnabled:(id)sender {
    self.helpButtonEnabled = !self.helpButtonEnabled;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you this was above and beyond and really helped out a beginner. I ended up using KVO observer.